# Division algorithm and Prime Numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

In my class, the professor went through a proof that if $p|xy$ then $p|x$ or $p|y$.  where p is a prime number. And now that I am reading through it, there is a small piece of the proof that I do not understand.  He used complete induction on x and said for all y, $p|x$ or $p|y$. He then used the division algorithm in the inductive step to get

$$p=q(x+1)+r$$
$$py=q(x+1)y+ry$$

So, since $p|py$ and $p|q(x+1)y$ then $p|ry$.  I don't understand how we know that $p|q(x+1)y$ and why that means $p|ry$.  Can anybody help me figure that out?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not write to the professor and ask?

Comment: what is $q$? A prime?

Comment: If $x$ is supposed to be identified with $n+1$, so the induction is on $x$, then $(n+1)y=xy$ is divisible by $p$ by hypothesis. Then $r\lt x$ and you can apply the inductive hypothesis to $ry$. But you haven't explained enough to make it clear how $x$ is related to what you have put down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that what you didn't write is that the argument you are having trouble with is trying to prove that $p \mid (x+1) y$ implies $p \mid x+1$ or $p \mid y$, and therefore $p \mid (x+1) y$ is taken as a hypothesis for that part of the argument.

You probably already know your other questions but just haven't thought of them:

- If $a \mid b$, then $a \mid bc$
- If $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$ then $a \mid b+c$

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different proof.

By strong induction, we can decompose a number into its prime factors. Do so with $ xy $. Since $ p | xy $ and $p$ is prime, $p$ is amongst them. It is therefore amongst the prime factors of $x$ or those of $y$.

Comment: How are you proving that prime factorisations are unique without using that p|xy implies p|x or p|y?

Comment: @meta Quite right. It's invalid. The word *its* is unwarranted. Let me think about this.